# Quicksort implemention on linkedlist in java

Tags: java, data-structures, quicksort

I wrote my own linkedlist in java and it is working without problem but when I want implement quicksort algorithm, it gives weird output, namely;

list elements respectively = 50, 30, 20, 10, 40, 60
output : 10 20 30 40 50 60

but

list elements respectively = 50, 30, 10, 40, 20, 60
output : 10 30 20 40 50 60

I tried debugging but I could not solve

```
public Node findByIndex(int index) {
    Node current = first;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        current = current.next;
    }

    return current;
}

public int listSize() {
    Node current = first;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        current = current.next;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

public void sortList() {
    sortList(0, listSize() - 1);
}

public void sortList(int low, int high) {
    Node pivot = findByIndex((low + high) / 2);
    int x = low, y = high;

    while (x <= y) {
        while (findByIndex(x).data < pivot.data) {
            x++;
        }

        while (findByIndex(y).data > pivot.data) {
            y--;
        }

        if (x <= y) {
            swap(x, y);
            x++;
            y--;
        }
    }

    if (x < high)
        sortList(x, high);
    if (low < y)
        sortList(low, y);
}

public void swap(int x, int y) {
    int temp = findByIndex(x).data;
    findByIndex(x).data = findByIndex(y).data;
    findByIndex(y).data = temp;
}
```

Comment: the most efficient way to sort a linked list is to copy it into an array, sort it and copy the elements back.

Comment: I think this way cause high cost and complexity, my problem is why this algorithm product distinct output on same inputs

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, what do you see.

Comment: A linked list is probably the least appropriate data structure to quiksort.  The usual practice is to make a temporary array and sort that.

Comment: Okay, presumably I should try this way, thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens:

At first, your list is:

```
┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│50│30│10│40│20│60│
└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
       ↑
     pivot
```

The pivot is 10 in this case. Scanning from the left, `x` points to `50`, so it stops there. `y`, on the other hand, stops at the `10`. Good, so we swap them. We get:

```
x=0 y=2
┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│10│30│50│40│20│60│
└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
       ↑
     pivot
```

But wait, you only swapped the data! The variable `pivot` is still pointing to the third `Node`. Now, instead of continuing to compare with `10`, **we are comparing with the `50` that replaced the data in the third node**.

This makes `y` stop at `1` and `x` move to `2`. So the list is divided incorrectly for the recursion. It should have divided to

```
┌──┐┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│10││30│50│40│20│60│
└──┘└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

But instead it is divided now as:

```
┌──┬──┐┌──┬──┬──┬──┐
│10│30││50│40│20│60│
└──┴──┘└──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

So what you should do is keep the pivot *data* in a local variable, rather than testing against `pivot.data`:

```
    Node pivot = findByIndex((low + high) / 2);
    int pivotData = pivot.data;
    int x = low, y = high;

    while (x <= y) {
        while (findByIndex(x).data < pivotData) {
            x++;
        }

        while (findByIndex(y).data > pivotData) {
            y--;
        }
```

---

That being said, your algorithm is *terribly* inefficient.

Every time you need to locate an item, you scan from the beginning of the list until that item. This adds O(n) to the complexity of the algorithm for every `findByIndex()`. The call to `listSize()` is also inefficient, but at least it's called only once. By doing the `findByIndex()` the way you did, you cancel out the entire effect of the recursive call that is supposed to give you O(n log n). And you use `findByIndex()` even inside the swap!

Comment: Okay, I get it and as you said my algorithm is really terrible I have noticed that now, I will change it, thanks a million :)